# How to fix 'no match for 'operator=='' when comparing strings in if statement

Tags: c++, operators, filestream

Trying to compare strings using if statements but getting operator errors. How can I fix this to make the statement compare the strings? Using Code::Blocks as compiler.

Full Raw code Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/DJGqJBwu (No longer public due to question solved)

(NOTE: Most of the commenting in raw code is for experimenting and there are tons of errors overall that I can go over later)

This is for a leaderboard I am trying to create for a Tic-Tac-Toe game. I have tried different ways to compare the strings to fix this such as .compare.

```
void admin (string names, int nameW[10], int wins[10], unsigned int a[10]) //called variables from main
{
    char repeat = 'y'; //used for function loop
    char resetAll; //used elsewhere
    int winCount; //used elsewhere
    string reset;
    string modify; //used elsewhere
    string admin; //used elsewhere

    cin >> reset;

        //Reset
        if (reset==names[0])
        {
            wins[0] = 0;
        }
}
```

Build log:

```
error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::__cxxll::string {aka std::__cxll::basic_string<char>}' and '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type {aka char}')
```

I am expecting the reset variable to be the same as the names[0] variable so that the code can execute. Results are that code cannot build and run (unable to test program).

Comment: `reset` is a `string` (multiple characters), while `names[0]` is a `char` (single character). The comparison makes no sense. Do you want to compare `reset` with `names` instead? Also `names` sounds plural, but it has type `string`, only _one_ name therefore. Maybe your function parameter is wrong and is supposed to be an array of `string` instead?

Comment: Since `names` is a `std::string`, `names[0]` is a char. You can't compare a single, lonely, attention-starved `char` with an entire, fat, `std::string`. What exactly were the results you were expecting, from that expierment?

Comment: Just for clarity, could you make the paste public, please?

Comment: No semantically equivalent but it can do the job: `if (reset[0]==names[0])`

Comment: I was expecting to create string arrays and compare each individual string within the array to a different answer from reset. Paste is public. (Still new to this)

Comment: Well then the function parameter is wrong, you are passing a single `string` not an array of `string` (or something similar) for `names`. Did you intend `string names[10]` in the parameter list?

Comment: Multiple people have explained to you the reason for the compilation error. That answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the admin function parameter where the string "names" did not declare the array.

Turn:

```
void admin (string names, ...
```

Into:

```
void admin (string name[10], ...
```